# Google direction api request returns NO_RESULTS in android app request, but works in browser

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-directions-api

I'm trying to query the directions api via an android app. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

When I build the request and try to execute it via android I just get a result of

```
{"routes":[],"status":"NOT_FOUND"}
```

But if i paste this in the browser it works just fine, an example.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=mykey&destination=38.2210514%2C-120.9770154&origin=36.299837%2C-121.7596924&mode=walking&departure_time=1410931203
```

where the api key is a browser key. I know what you're thinking a browser key wont work for android app requests, well the referers for the api key is set to any so it should not matter. When I try to use a diffrent key that is designated for the mobile which works for maps i get this error.

```
{"error_message":"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.","routes":[],"status":"REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

Here is the java code that executes the request its using spring

```
 Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https").authority("maps.googleapis.com").appendPath("maps").appendPath("api").appendPath("directions").appendPath("json")
            .appendQueryParameter("key", "***")
            .appendQueryParameter("destination","39.2210514,-120.9770154")
            .appendQueryParameter("origin", "39.299837,-120.7596924")
            .appendQueryParameter("mode", mode)
            .appendQueryParameter("departure_time", String.valueOf(unixTime));

    String url = builder.build().toString();

    app.log(url);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
    JsonObject response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, JsonObject.class);

    app.log(response.toString());
```

Comment: Have you tried to print your url in logcat ? Make sure the correct key is passed in url.

Comment: Yeah, copying the request in logcat in android to browser works.